# Переопределение render в дочернем action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mvc, ruby, перегрузка-операторов

Возможно ли в Ruby on Rails переопределить `render` в дочернем контроллере?

```
def new
   super # рендерит определенную View
end
```

Было бы удобно переопределить только `render`, чтобы не копировать весь родительский `action`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, можно

Например так:

```
protected

def render *args
  super nothing: true
end
```

UPD:
Для того, чтобы экшене дочернего контроллера выполнить кастомный рендер используйте блок.

Пример.
Родительский контроллер

```
class ParentController < ApplicationController
  def new
    # Такая то логика
    if block_given?
      yield(<параметры для блока>)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

Дочерний контроллер

```
class ChildController < ParentController
  def new
    super do |<параметры для блока>|
      render "<такой-то шаблон>"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что у меня не один action в этом контроллере, мне нужно в каждом из них переопределить родительский рендер:

```
def new
    super # render прошел
    # render 'account/new' - вызовет multiple render error
end

def index
    super # render прошел
    # render 'account/index' - вызовет multiple render error
end
```

Получается что родительский рендер происходит и при вызове дочернего возникает ошибка о multiple render.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.